# Is it possible to simulate connection timeout using wiremock tools?

Tags: java, wiremock

I know that it can simulate `SocketTimeoutException` by using `withFixedDelay`, but what about `ConnectionTimeoutException`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do this with WireMock by calling `addDelayBeforeProcessingRequests(300)` against the Java API or posting the following to `http://<host>:<port>/__admin/socket-delay`:

`{ "milliseconds": 300 }`

(Obviously replacing 300 with however many milliseconds you'd like to delay by)

Comment: addDelayBeforeProcessingRequests() doesn't seem to exist in 2.1.12. Is there an alternative?

Comment: what would be the json element for this ?

Comment: For those who are looking for those methods like me:
This method was removed in version 2.x without any replacement. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wiremock-user/KEoBPIohVKU/Rm6lTOPQAAAJ

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the answer to this question has been "No", since [version 2.0.8-beta](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/commit/4040f9d86a6dc741ef16487996a89f6e0ed1b678#diff-d623a4213f1416b3ddf10eba133d2fbahttps://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/commit/4040f9d86a6dc741ef16487996a89f6e0ed1b678#diff-d623a4213f1416b3ddf10eba133d2fba).

Tom (author of WireMock) explains why [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/591):

> It's basically impossible to reliably force connection timeouts in pure Java at the moment.
>
> It used to be the case that you could inject a delay before calling `.accept()` on the socket, but that stopped working a while back, I guess due to a change in the implementation internals.
>
> My recommendation at the moment would be to use a tool that works at the level of the network stack. `iptables ... -j DROP` type commands will do the trick, or if you want a level of automation over this you can use tools such as https://github.com/tomakehurst/saboteur or https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba.

He also goes on to explain that just stopping WireMock doesn't achieve the same thing:

> shutting down WireMock won't have the same effect - when a port is not being listened on, you get a TCP `RST` (reset) packet back, whereas a connection timeout happens when you get nothing back from the server in the timeout window after your initial `SYN` packet.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout https://github.com/tomakehurst/saboteur which allows you to simulate network issues. Or you can do it your self with iptables.

Answer (score 2):

When using [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Stubbing#simulating-delays), adding a delay is also possible.

Example:

```cs
var server = WireMockServer.Start();

// add a delay of 30 seconds for all requests
server.AddRequestProcessingDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

or

```cs
var server = WireMockServer.Start();
server
  .Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/slow"))
  .RespondWith(
    Responses.Create()
      .WithStatusCode(200)
      .WithBody(@"{ ""msg"": ""Hello I'm a little bit slow!"" }")
      .WithDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code mock a get call to /service-url where it returns only after the duration specified.

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.urlPathEqualTo;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.ResponseDefinitionBuilder;
import java.time.Duration;
import static java.lang.Math.toIntExact;

void mockServiceUrlWithDelay(Duration delay) throws JSONException {
        ResponseDefinitionBuilder jsonResponse = aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .withBody(new JSONObject() 
                        .put("key", "value") 
                        .toString())
                .withFixedDelay(toIntExact(delay.toMillis()));
        stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/service-url")).willReturn(jsonResponse));
    }
```